# Cross-table serialization Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, geojson, geodjango

I have two models with a many-to-many relationship and I am trying to return some geojson by using the Django REST Framework. The data I am trying to return is th pub_date and coordinates (represented by a PointField in GeoDjango). Everytime I try and return the geojson I get the error `Field name 'city' is not valid for model 'Article'`. I'm pretty new to django/geodjango and this is the first time I've used the Django REST Framework. I've gone through the docs but can't work out where I'm going wrong (or maybe even where to start).

Here my models and serializers.

models.py:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    continent = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    point = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.point)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'location'

class Article(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    locations = models.ManyToManyField(Location, related_name='places')
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique_for_date="pub_date")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    article_keywords = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True), size=10), size=10,)
    title_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    section_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s' % (self.article_title, self.pub_date, self.article_keywords)     

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'article'
```

serializers.py

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    places = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('places')
```

And the output I would like:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "time": "2013-01-22 08:42:26+01"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                7.582512743,
                51.933292258,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "time": "2013-01-22 10:00:26+01"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                7.602516645,
                51.94962073,
                1
            ]
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE! I managed to get somewhere with a raw SQL query embeded in a queryset but this is not not quite right:

```
serialize('geojson', Article.objects.raw('
select a.id, a.pub_date, al.location_id, l.point 
from article a 
join article_locations al on a.id = al.article_id 
join location l on al.location_id = l.id'),
geometry_field = 'point',
fields=('pub_date','locations',))
```

The result is this:

```
{  
"type":"FeatureCollection",
"crs":{  
    "type":"name",
    "properties":{  
        "name":"EPSG:4326"
    }
},
"features":[  
    {  
        "geometry":null,
        "type":"Feature",
        "properties":{  
            "pub_date":"2015-04-06T20:38:59Z",
            "locations":[  
                3
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused... you json has nothing related with the models you posted. Please read what's the purpose of the [`serializers`](www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/a) in DRF. And one more thing, you can't use `places` inside `ArticleSerializer` since it's not an `Article` field.

Comment: Sorry, not the clearest question. All I want is to return all article pub_dates and their corresponding article coordinates lat/long's (from the pointField). Like I say, I'm pretty new to this and more used to SQL where I know what I'm doing with relational joins...here I'm kind of stumped!

Answer (score 6):

DRF serializers can do two things:

1. Serialize complex data *(such as querysets)* to native Python datatypes

   ```
   serializer = CommentSerializer(comment)
   serializer.data
   # {'email': u'leila@example.com', 'content': u'foo bar', 'created': datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 22, 16, 20, 9, 822774)}
   ```
2. Deserialize data from native Python datatypes

   ```
   serializer = CommentSerializer(data=data)
   serializer.is_valid()
   # True
   serializer.validated_data
   # {'content': 'foo bar', 'email': 'leila@example.com', 'created': datetime.datetime(2012, 08, 22, 16, 20, 09, 822243)}
   ```

In your case where

> All I want is to return all article pub_dates and their corresponding
>   article coordinates lat/long's (from the pointField).

You will have to do two things:

1. Create a complex data structure using either an `object`, a `list` of objects or a `queryset`.

   In your case this is pretty easy, you just need a queryset with all articles and with [`prefetched`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) locations in order to prevent unnecessary db hits for each `location`.

   ```
   Article.objects.all().prefetch_related('locations')[:10]
   ```
2. Create a serializer which can serialize this queryset.

   Since you have nested data structure *(one `article` can have many `locations`)* you better split this into two separate serializers.

   The first one will know how to serialize `locations` only, and the second one will know how to serialize `articles` only, but it will use the first one for the `article.locations` serialization.

   ```
   class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
           model = Location
           fields = ('point',)


   class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       #this way we override the default serialization 
       #behaviour for this field.
       locations = LocationSerializer(many=True)

       class Meta:
           model = Article
           fields = ('pub_date', 'locations')
   ```

Finally you can combine `1` and `2` via a [ViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    #read about pagination in order to split this into pages
    queryset = Article.objects.all().prefetch_related('locations')[:10]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried implementing but the returned output is still just the content of the Articles table (minus the authors and locations). I managed to get somewhere with a raw SQL query embeded in a queryset but this is still not producing the desired results. I have updated abve to show the SQL query.

Comment: I think your problems comes from the fact that DRF serializers do not support GeoDjango geometry fields out of the box. Checkout this module should be in help. [django-rest-framework-gis](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis)