# Serializing joined tables in serializers rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

So i am trying to serialize multiple joined tables with django serializers. I cant find a way to do this. The query being executed is raw sql.
The models are as below

```
class UserDetail(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField()
    national_id = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    merchant_name = models.CharField(null = True, max_length = 30)

class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    account_number = models.BigIntegerField()
    balance = models.FloatField()
    account_type = models.ForeignKey(AccountType, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

The json for the expected result should as below

```
{
  "userdetail": {
                 "mobile_number":""
              },
  "account": {
              "account_number":""
          },
  "user": {
  "first_name": "",
  "last_name": "",
  "email":""
      }
  }
```

The raw sql query is as below

```
queryset = Account.objects.raw('''SELECT auth_user.first_name,
                                                 auth_user.id,
                                                 auth_user.last_name,
                                                 auth_user.email,
                                                 authentication_userdetail.mobile_number,
                                                 authentication_account.account_number
                                           FROM
                                                 public.auth_user,
                                                 public.authentication_account,
                                                 public.authentication_userdetail
                                           WHERE
                                                 auth_user.id = authentication_userdetail.user_id
                                           AND
                                                 auth_user.id = authentication_account.user_id
                                        ''')
```

If there is an alternative way to do this without using raw sql i would greatly appreciate it as im not a fan of executing raw sql queries with django ORM

Tried working with this solution but i cant seem to understand the way the queryset was serialized
[Cross-table serialization Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902287/cross-table-serialization-django-rest-framework)

**Edited**

```
class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserDetail
        fields = ('mobile_number',)

class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('account_number',)


class AccountInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_detail = UserDetailSerializer()
    account = AccountSerializer()
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('user_detail', 'account', 'user')
    def get_user(self, obj):
        return {
            'first_name': 'obj.first_name',
            'last_name': 'obj.last_name',
            'email': 'obj.email',
           }
```

**Code for the view**

```
serializer_class = AccountInfoSerializer

def get_queryset(self, *args, ** kwargs):
    user_id = self.request.query_params.get('user_id', None)
    queryset = None
    if user_id is not '':
        queryset = UserDetail.objects.raw()
    return queryset
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try such solution:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserDetail
        fields = ('mobile_number',)


class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('account_number',)


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userdetail = UserDetailSerializer()
    account = AccountSerializer()
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('userdetail', 'account', 'user')

    def get_user(self, obj):
        return {
            'first_name': 'obj.first_name',
            'last_name': 'obj.last_name',
            'email': 'obj.email',
            }
```

Comment: Its returning AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user_detail` on serializer UserSerializer`. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `UserDetail` instance

Comment: `class AccountInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_detail = UserDetailSerializer()
    account = AccountSerializer()
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('user_detail', 'account', 'user')
    def get_user(self, obj):
        return {
            'first_name': 'obj.first_name',
            'last_name': 'obj.last_name',
            'email': 'obj.email',
            }`

Comment: not need the code of the serializer, how did you call it, example
`instance = User.objects.last(); serializer = AccountInfoSerializer(instance)`

Comment: `AccountInfoSerializer` has meta model `User` but in the `queryset` you return query to `UserDetail` change it to `User`

Comment: Thanks it worked. Fixed where you highlighted and also found out that the field name was not the same as the model name for UserDetail

Comment: glad to help you!

Comment: wondering how can one goes about getting a flat result structure, instead of the output structure above, how about { "mobile_number": 1234, "account_number": 54545, "user" : "bob", .......} ?